# Is there any way to handle special characters used in a directory for batch file command?

Tags: batch-file

My batch file command is:

```
RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\! RD /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\!
```

As you can see, I'm trying to delete the ! folder and its subfolders. I have tried using single and double quotes, backtick, and backslash to handle each character of the said folder but nothing seems to work.

What can I do to handle this in batch file command?

**[Edit /]**

The text name of the directory as shown above does not use the standard ANSI characters. Copied from above, to a UTF-8 encoded file, and showed in Hex mode, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Which is it now? `Powershell` or `batch-file`?

Comment: I have added additional information to your question, because you did not make clear that all of the characters you used for thar directroy name were not in the standard range of ANSI characters. If my additional information is incorrect, please make an effort to reproduce it fixed.

Comment: @Gerhard Hi! It's for batch file. Thanks.

Comment: @Compo All good with the edit. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do I add a circumflex before each special character. That's this ^ symbol. Stick one of those before any affected character and it should run fine without affecting your code.

Comment: I added ^ and it didn't solve it. This is what I did with the command:

RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\!^^^^^^^^^^^123 RD /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\!^^^^^^^^^^^123

but I am getting this:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts>RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\!≡¥Öï≡¥Ö¥≡¥Öñ≡¥Ö⌐≡¥Öñ≡¥Ö£≡¥Öº≡¥Öû≡¥ÖÑ≡¥Ö¥≡¥Ö«123 RD /S /Q C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\!≡¥Öï≡¥Ö¥≡¥Öñ≡¥Ö⌐≡¥Öñ≡¥Ö£≡¥Öº≡¥Öû≡¥ÖÑ≡¥Ö¥≡¥Ö«123
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Apologies if it doesn't have a proper format of what I'm trying to show you but I hope I am clear.

Comment: Are the file paths correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I just copied it from the File Explorer so I won't miss out anything.